# ES6 syntax are highlighted as error in .vue files in WebStorm. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, webstorm, babeljs

[image]

WebStorm version: 10.0.1

Above image shows the JavaScript part of the .vue file. It works without problems but the IDE highlights the ES6 syntax as an error.

I saw people recommending using `type="text/babel"` or `type="text/ecmascript-6"` but in both cases it is all grey and there is no highlight:

[image]

In [this thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/70) it asks about my exact problem. Developer says it's gonna be fixed. (Though I thought the problem is IDE related).

It must be a very common problem among WebStorm users as most people use ES6 with Vue. Anyone fixed this?

Comment: Have you setup WebStrom to enterpret JavaScript as ES6?

Comment: @E.Sundin Yes, it has no problems with .js files.

Comment: Does adding `lang="babel"` to the script tag help? `<script lang="babel" type="text/babel">...</script>`

Comment: @Barthy Nope, it didn't help.

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: Set javascript version in settings

Comment: I had the same issue, I think I resolved it by installing the Vue.js plugin

Comment: Please **always** state your IDE version when reporting such stuff. So far it could be that you are using older IDE version... And I assume that you do have Vue.js plugin installed, right?

Comment: Edited post with webstorm version

Comment: @LazyOne Yes I have the vue.js plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WebStorm version (10.0.1) is too old.

Adding the `type="text/babel"` to the `<script>` tag suggestion -- it's supported since 10.0.3 only.

The "proper" fix for ES6 in inline scripts is available in WebStorm **2016.2** (which is over 1 year old already) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16444

---

I suggest to get latest WebStorm 2017.2.5 and give it a go (see how your code works there).

Note that it now comes with own Vue.js plugin bundled .. so you may need to remove your plugin first (if you plan to import settings from current version).